# Is it possible to use ensyms on a character vector?

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

In the following example, why am I getting an error or unexpected
results from using ensyms to take in a character vector argument?
I realize that this particular example is silly: facet_grid()
can actually take a character vector as an argument.  However, I want
to understand how to use sym, ensym, syms, and ensyms with
confidence, more generally.

I've written a small piece of code that facets a graph made in ggplot via a character vector.

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)
n <- 100
x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
c1 <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
c2 <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)

df_ex <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, c1=c1, c2=c2)
    plot_test <- function(dat, facet_vars){
    facet_vars <- ensyms(facet_vars)
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x1,x2)) + facet_grid(vars(!!!facet_vars))
}
facet_vars <- c("c1", "c2")
#throws error
p <- plot_test(df_ex, c("c1", "c2"))
#seems to look for variable `facet_var`
p <- plot_test(df_ex, facet_vars)
```

If the character vector is directly input into the function I get the error "Error: Must supply symbols or strings as argument."  If I input facet_vars, ensyms seems to literally return "facet_vars" and the faceting is not performed.  Is there a way to use ensyms without taking arguments from ellipsis, which is the use I'm most familiar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `ensym` if you want to pass a symbol or string to your function via non-standard evaluation. That's not what you are doing with `c("c1", "c2")`. This is not a vector literal in R. Here you are calling the function `c()` with two parameters to return a vector. This is not a simple strin; this is a function call. Instead, if you want to turn a vector of strings into symbols, just use `syms()`. These will work:

```
plot_test <- function(dat, facet_vars){
  facet_vars <- syms(facet_vars)
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x1,x2)) + facet_grid(vars(!!!facet_vars))
}
facet_vars <- c("c1", "c2")
plot_test(df_ex, c("c1", "c2"))
plot_test(df_ex, facet_vars)
```

or alternatively, capture it as an expression

```
plot_test <- function(dat, facet_vars){
  facet_vars <- enexprs(facet_vars)
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x1,x2)) + facet_grid(vars(!!!facet_vars))
}
```

The `ensyms()` works better if you are passing strings as separate parameters

```
plot_test <- function(dat, ...){
  facet_vars <- ensyms(...)
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x1,x2)) + facet_grid(vars(!!!facet_vars))
}
plot_test(df_ex, "c1", "c2")
```

Comment: You're first comment about proper usage of ensym is helpful, but capturing it with syms or enexprs isn't working when I try it out.  Using syms, gets rid of the error, but it produces facets with no points in them.  The same goes for enexprs.  Did the graphs show up properly for you?

Comment: You don't have a `geom_point()` at all in your code so there's nothing to draw any points. I was just focusing on the faceting.

Comment: Oh, of course, I accidentally removed it while transferring my code to SO.  Thank You.